# node.js URL module throws an error when parsing the URL directly from the Request object of the http server

Tags: node.js, url, module, ubuntu-22.04, url-parsing

Node.js v18.15.0
Ubuntu 22.04
NPM 9.5.0

When creating the routing operations of my node.js http server, the WHATWG URL standard throws an error when I pass it the response.url directly.

```
const httpServer = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    const requestURL = new URL(req.url);
    const requestHostname = requestURL.hostname;
    const requestPathname = requestURL.pathname;
    const requestParams = requestURL.searchParams;
    console.log(requestPathname);
```

results in the following error:

```
node:internal/url:566
  throw new ERR_INVALID_URL(input);
  ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:566:9)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:646:5)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/var/www/newsat11.live/index.js:26:24)
    at Server.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at parserOnIncoming (node:_http_server:1072:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17) {
  input: '/',
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL'
}

Node.js v18.15.0
```

I'm trying to move from the legacy API for the node.js URL module which works perfectly with this syntax and console logs the values as verification.

```
const httpServer = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    const requestURL = new url.parse(req.url);
    const requestHostname = requestURL.hostname;
    const requestPathname = requestURL.pathname;
    const requestParams = requestURL.searchParams;
    console.log(requestPathname); // logs "/" as the pathname for localhost
```

Comment: What is the value of `requestHostname` in the working version?

Comment: The request hostname is null, as it's a local environment. I'm dev-ing locally until all of the configurations are done. @Konrad